# USB host mode. UsbDevice is always in status attached even when I dettached it

Tags: android, usbserial

I'm making an application that communicate with a UsbDevice in `USB host mode`. I used the `BroadcastReceiver` to detect the connection, so when device attached, the communication begins and my app gets data from this `UsbDevice`, then it stops when device dettached. But sometimes, even when I pull the cable out, it still is in the attached status so continues getting data and then crashs (because no data is transferred). Anybody has idea about this? Thank for reading